# Get the list of Task in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, task

I created a Task in a webapi controller and I would like to verify the task status from other controller. Could I access to the list of created tasks in my application in order to verify the status.

Comment: What have you tried so far, could you provide us with some code and context?

Comment: That would be from another Request? I wouldn't do that. Nothing will guarantee that .NET will keep that task alive.

Comment: Request the task status from different controllers

Comment: If the task is killed, it is other status to verify

Comment: Assuming there is not only one `task` whose status you'd want ,then you could create a separate `static List<Task>`  in your `Controller` or even better outside in a separate `service` that can get injected via `DI`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it adding the task to the singleton application instance. One controller create/update the task and the other read the status using the singleton. A similar solution

Answer (score 1):

You could create a record in the database when starting the task and update it once the task is terminating.